# How to redirect to a modal popup of bootstrap in angular2?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular, popup, angular2-routing

I am making an angular2 application. I have login in modal popup of bootstrap in the homepage route. I am implementing a guard to other routes. I want to redirect the users to the popup login when the guard specifies that the user is not logged in. I have the following pop up login code in homepage or root route:

```
<div class="account-modal modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body custom-modal-body">
            <form>
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username"/>
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password"> name="password">
                <input type="submit" value="login"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now what i want to do is navigate to this pop up using the router's navigate function in the auth guard i.e:

```
this.router.navigate(['/']); //there should be link to the popup login
```

But i have not been able to point it to the above modal class.

Can anyone help me how to use the router's navigate to point the url to the modal popup?

Comment: use auxilary routes